# How to get the data which are not soled from the given tables? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

i have `products table` as 
  product_id  int type with primary key constraint

product name varchar with not null constraint

sample data like as below

```
1.  100, 'Nokia'
2.  200, 'IPhone'
3.  300, 'Samsung'
4.  400, 'LG'
```

i have the `sales table` as

SALE_ID    with  int type,

PRODUCT_ID with int type referece of product table (foregin key)

YEAR       with int type

Quantity   with  int type

PRICE      with int type check price > 0

sample data like as below

```
 1, 100, 2010, 25, 5000
 2, 100, 2011, 16, 5000
 3, 100, 2012, 8,  5000
 4, 200, 2010, 10, 9000
 5, 200, 2011, 15, 9000
 6, 200, 2012, 20, 9000
 7, 300, 2010, 20, 7000
 8, 300, 2011, 18, 7000
 9, 300, 2012, 20, 7000
```

**Query**
How to find the products which are not soled?

Comment: do we have any functions!! i'm new to PostgreSQL!! i'm sorry if it is a not considered as a doubt!

Comment: I don't think you can "get data that's not present". Am I the only one who feels that's a contradiction?

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry its a mistake... i mean to ask how can i get the products which  are not soled

Comment: @user2561626 When asking questions on SO, try to show at least some atempts to solve the problem. SO isnt for solving the problems for you, it is for helping you to solve them yourself.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko thank u :-) for suggesting me a good way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Praveen

Your solution is subtly incorrect, because there's `no NOT NULL constraint on product_id` in sales. It builds a list then filters on the list, but the list could contain NULL, and 2 NOT IN (1, NULL) is NULL, which in WHERE is treated as false.

It is much better to re-phrase this as

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sales s WHERE s.product_id = products.product_id)
```

The Query ::

```
select * 
from products 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM sales s WHERE s.product_id = products.product_id);
```

@igor-romanchenko

Comment: great. This is a perfect share.. My +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from products 
where product_id not in (select PRODUCT_ID 
                         from sales 
                         where PRODUCT_ID  is not null);
```

Comment: @Igor . will removing distinct makes any difference?

Comment: @Praveen It wont change the results of the query, but might make it faster.

Comment: @Praveen Also, it is usefull to add `WHERE PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL` to the inner query. Currently if any `PRODUCT_ID` in `sales` table is `null` the whole query will return no results.

Comment: Great.. Updated the answer. Thanks for the info about the performance.